# logcat indicate error?

Tags: android, logcat

hi now i am create simple andengine application...now my logcat indicate error....what mistake i made for my application.....

```
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280): Failed loading Bitmap in 
    AssetTextureSource.AssetPath: ggg
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280): java.io.FileNotFoundException: ggg
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.content.res
    .AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.content.res
   .AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.content.res
   .AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl
   .texture.source.AssetTextureSource.<init>(AssetTextureSource.java:46)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at org.anddev
   .andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory
   .createFromAsset(TextureRegionFactory.java:66)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at org.anddev
    .andengine.examples.minimal
   .AndEngineMinimalExample.onLoadResources(AndEngineMinimalExample.java:59)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity
   .BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:158)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity
   .BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:83)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl
   .PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:1981)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.view.View
   .dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3788)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.view.ViewGroup
  . dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:658)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.view.ViewRoot
   .handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1921)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.os.Handler
   .dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.os.Looper
   .loop(Looper.java:123)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.app.ActivityThread
    .main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method
   .invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method
    .invoke(Method.java:521)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at com.android.internal.os
   .ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at com.android.internal.os
    .ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    02-09 13:05:01.560: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at dalvik.system
    .NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-09 13:05:02.330: ERROR/AndEngine(280): Failed loading Bitmap in  
    AssetTextureSource. AssetPath: ggg
    02-09 13:05:02.330: ERROR/AndEngine(280): java.io.FileNotFoundException: ggg
    02-09 13:05:02.330: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at 
    android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
    02-09 13:05:02.330: ERROR/AndEngine(280):     at android.content.res
   .AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
```

Comment: You are trying to load an image and it fails. Show us the code that is causing the exception.

Comment: it looks like you are referencing a drawable (bitmap file) called ggg and its not availble in your res folder.

Comment: so is there going to be an explanation from the OP about what he/she did to correct the mistake? Otherwise this question is just a waste of everyone's time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load an asset that does not exist. Without seeing your code, it's hard to say more. You can scan down the stack trace until you get to a line that corresponds to your code. The line number will tell you where to look for a problem.